# Is there any way to schedule an event without constantly running checks

Tags: algorithm, micro-optimization

Let's say I want to run a function when certain conditions are met, for example I want to show a pop up message at a certain hour. Do I have to keep checking every so often or is there any other way to schedule an event without having to have a constant loop? The language doesn't matter, I'd just like to know the algorithm if it exists.

Comment: Do you want to compute other things during this waiting time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, timers exist, you don't need to busy-wait checking the time.

Any OS worthy of the name has `sleep` functions (sometimes by that name) to sleep for a fixed number of seconds, and/or `alarm` functions that take a wake-up time.  Timers are or can be hardware-supported so the OS isn't busy-waiting either.

POSIX [`alarm(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html) takes a time in seconds, not a time-of-day, but unlike POSIX [`sleep(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) it can't "wake up early".  So you could set an alarm and then use `sleep` until the alarm wakes you up.  Or do other things before the SIGALRM.